# Meaning of text annotation in NLP context

Tags: nlp, text-processing

In Natural Language Processing, what does it mean to annotate a corpus?
Does it simply mean to add labels to text (i.e. "positive, negative & neutral" classes in a sentiment analysis task)? Or there is more to its meaning/definition?

Comment: Would this be better on https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to annotate a speech corpus - meaning that *there is not the one correct way of annotation*. A good overview to that topic is given **[here](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/natural-language-annotation/9781449332693/ch01.html)**.

Annotation always relates to the speech aspect you want to investigate and the stage of speech processing you are aiming at. Just think about several tasks within Natural Language Processing.

- **Automatic Speech Recognition**: Here, a correct annotation would be the exact transcription of what is being said. Additionally, transcriptions here can be made on word-, syllable- or triphone-level.
- **Speaker Recognition**: When voice characteristics are used to classify the speaker of a specific utterance, the annotation might just apply to the speaking person.
- **Emotional Alignment**: For a classification, whole sentences or utterances needs to be labeled with the underlying emotion.

All in all, annotating a speech corpus means to manually add labels to it, but you should always be specific in what you want describe or investigate and why.